# Bluetooth LE / Classic capablilities of iOS and MacOS

Tags: ios, macos, core-bluetooth, rfcomm, iobluetooth

I want to create an App that should transfer data via Bluetooth but I'm new to developing apps for Mac / iPhone.
The app needs to...

- ... scan for and detect BLe advertisements with a specific manufacturerId (Not apples)
  ([like I can on android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder#addManufacturerData(int,%20byte%5B%5D)))
- ... connect via `rfcomm` to a device (e.g. android) via mac-address that's encoded in the manufacturer data

The question now is whether I can accomplish this with `CoreBluetooth` and / or `IOBluetooth` on MacOs and / or iOS.

*For those who are interested:* The app should be a port of [my android app](https://github.com/nearby-sharing/android) using dotnet / Xamarin.

Comment: IOBluetooth on Mac, probably. Core Bluetooth on iOS, definitely not. There is no access to legacy profiles, such as RFComm on iOS and no access to peripheral MAC addresses.